# Add values of starting row and next row based on a colum from other table

Tags: postgresql, case, cumulative-sum, with-statement

I have two tables.

**TABLE A**

| Product | Plant | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11248 | ABC12 | 65 |
| 98490 | GHI34 | 54 |
| 11248 | DEF56 | 25 |

**TABLE B**

| Product | Plant | Week | Sales | Production |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11248 | ABC12 | 0 | 7894 | 38410 |
| 11248 | ABC12 | ... | ... | ... |
| 11248 | ABC12 | 11 | 6887 | 84351 |

First, I would like to add the only value of stock from TABLE A in the week 0 like the table below

| Product | Plant | Week | Sales | Production | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11248 | ABC12 | 0 | 7894 | 38410 | 65 |

Second, calculate the stock from the rest of the week using the operation `(Production+Stock)-Sales` and get a table like this.

| Product | Plant | Week | Sales | Production | Stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 11248 | ABC12 | 0 | 7894 | 38410 | 65 |
| 11248 | ABC12 | 1 | 6587 | 87427 | (87427+65)-6587= 80905 |
| 11248 | ABC12 | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 11248 | ABC12 | 11 | 6887 | 84351 | (84351+Stock_row10)-6887=NewStock |

I try two query's

The first query:

```
with Table_A1 (Product,  Plant, Stock) as (select Product,  Plant, Stock from TABLE_A)
          select Product, 
                Plant, 
                Week, 
                Sales, 
                Production, 
          from TABLE_B;
case 
  when Table_A1.Product = TABLE_B.Product and w.Plant=TABLE_B.Plant and TABLE_B.Week=0 then TABLE_A.Stock
  when Table_A1.Product = TABLE_B.Product and w.Plant=TABLE_B.Plant and TABLE_B.Week=1 then (TABLE_B.Production+TABLE_A.Stock)-TABLE_B.Sales
end ;
```

But I got the error "ERROR: Syntax error at or near 'from' "

The second query:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_B
ADD Stock INT;

SELECT * from TABLE_B
inner join TABLE_A ON TABLE_A.Product=TABLE_B.Product
case 
when Table_A1.Product = TABLE_B.Product and w.Plant=TABLE_B.Plant and TABLE_B.Week=0 then TABLE_A.Stock
end;
```

But I got the error "ERROR: Syntax error at or near 'CASE' ". Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a window function for this.

Your use case is complicated by the fact that your desired results show the initial stock is the stock at the first week's end.  I have seen that before, and I carry forward the first week's sales and production to adjust for their exclusion from later stock calculations:

```
with nets as (
  select a.product, a.plant, b.week, 
         b.sales, b.production, 
         sum(b.sales) over w as running_sales,
         sum(b.production) over w as running_production,
         first_value(b.sales) over w as first_week_sales,
         first_value(b.production) over w as first_week_production,
         a.stock as first_week_stock
    from table_a a
         join table_b b on (b.product, b.plant) = (a.product, a.plant)
  window w as (partition by a.product, a.plant order by b.week)
)
select product, plant, week, sales, production, 
       running_production + first_week_stock - first_week_production
       - running_sales + first_week_sales as stock
  from nets;
```

Working [fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/MI0x5iDK)

Comment: Thank you four for your help but I have a problem with the join statement and is that it is repeating the values i.e, I have 6 values of `product 11248 Plant ABC12 Week 0` is it possible do it without join?

Comment: @Rocruc  If you do not join, then how do you get your starting stock number?  Please edit and update your question with the new information about the repeated rows.  Make sure there is enough there to troubleshoot the problem.